# Search all files in directory PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to search all of the files in a directory instead of one, but I don't know what to use to do that.

**results.php:**

```
<?php
// error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
$file = 'db/test.txt';
$searchfor = $_GET['q'];
if (!$_GET['q']) { // returns this if query is empty
     echo "Search something.";
}
else {

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');

// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";

// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches))
    {
    echo "<centerResults</center><br>";
    echo "<pre>";
    echo implode($matches[0]);
    echo "</pre>";
    }
    else
{
   echo "<center>No results</center>";
}
}
```

I wanted to do something like this on line 3:

`$file = 'db/*';`

So that it could search through test.txt, and other txt files in that directory.

And i've tried googling, and nothing helpful has come up, any help?

Comment: No point re-inventing the wheel that PHP natively offers, just use [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). The likely flag you may want to use is `GLOB_BRACE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ther is function called **glob** it accept a required parameter which is the path and it can be a  pattern of the files and it return an array of the paths of all the files that match that pattern .
in other words , you can use this function with  "**dir/*.txt**" and it is going to return all the files that ar in the *dir* folder and has the *txt* extension